# .net core 7: get a list with null-values from appsettings

Tags: c#, .net-core, configurationmanager

I'm using dotnet core 6/7 and try to bind a list of Settings.

Imagine the following appsettings:

```json
{
  "parameters": [
    null,
    null,
    {
       "name": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

together with the following models:

```cs
public class ParameterDefinition : List<Parameter?> {}

public class Parameter {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which are configured somewhere in the `ConfigureServices`-Section:

```
services.Configure<ParameterDefinition>(Configuration.GetSection("parameters"));
```

The ConfigurationProvider shows the correct entries like:

```
"parameters:0": "",
"parameters:1": "",
"parameters:2:name": "test"
```

When getting the configuration via dependency injection (`IOptions<ParameterDefinition>`) the `ParameterDefinition` only contains one element, but it should have three, were the first two of them are null.

How can I correctly get the List including the `null`-values?

Comment: You stated, "The ConfigurationProvider shows the correct entries like:" but it is not true, because you see empty strings, not null values. I think that your issue is connected with this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36510

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, the `ConfigurationProvider` holds all entries; the `null` ones have become an empty string. These somewhere get lost when being processed towards a settings class.

To work around the issue:

1. Declare that `Parameter` `class` as a `struct`.

```
public struct Parameter
{
    public Parameter()
    { }

    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

**UPDATE**: As from your comment on this post, this suffices to solve the issue.

Below steps 2 and 3 are optional. Leaving these here for future reference, in case someones settings model looks similar.

---

2. Change the `ParameterDefinition` class from being/inheriting a `List<T>` to a `class` having an array (or `List<T>`) property of type `Parameter?`.

```
public class ParameterDefinition
{
    public Parameter?[] Parameters { get; set; } = default!;

    // Or public List<Parameter?> Parameters { get; set; } = default!;

}
```

3. Register the `IOptions<ParameterDefinition>` as below. *The json structure can stay as-is.*

```
services.AddOptions<ParameterDefinition>().BindConfiguration("");
```

Since you don't have a `"ParameterDefinition"` element/section in your json setup, an empty string is passed to [`BindConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsbuilderconfigurationextensions.bindconfiguration).

Alternatively, you can call the `Configure` method that you are already using, but that does require an additional `ParameterDefinition` json wrapper element/section.

```
services.Configure<ParameterDefinition>(Configuration.GetSection("ParameterDefinition"));
```

```
"ParameterDefinition": {
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "Name": "test"
    },
    null,
    null
  ]
}
```

---

Now when an `IOptions<ParameterDefinition>` instance gets injected, it will hold 3 items; 1 `Parameter` instance and 2 `null` values.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for giving me the right solution!
It was enough to just change the type defintion from `class` to `struct`